# Swig upgrade 2.0.12 to 3.0.12: %typemaps_string changed

Tags: swig, typemaps

I'd like to upgrade from Swig 2->3 and now I'm facing a problem in a typemap definition. One thing is, that I'm not very familiar with swig so far and just ran into really old legacy code defining something with `typemaps_string`.

The code seems to do some typemapping between QString (C++) to Perl.

The command/macro that swig>=3.0.0 is complaining about with the message *"error : Macro '%typemaps_string' expects 11 arguments"* is

```
%typemaps_string(%checkcode(UNISTRING), %checkcode(UNICHAR),
     QChar, QChar,
     SWIG_AsQtChPtrAndSize, 
     SWIG_FromQtChPtrAndSize,
     Qt_init,
     "<qt_string.h>", (-2147483647 - 1), 2147483647);
```

Unfortunately I couldn't find any information about the %typemaps_string macro. This change happend exactly by the update from Swig 2.0.12 to Swig 3.0.0. Out of the changelog I couldn't get any useful information as well (but that may be a result of my lacking knowledge of Swig).

Any information what this macro is used for and what changed since Swig3.x?

Here's the complete code of the file where this happens:

```
%include <perlstrings.swg>

%fragment("<qt_string.h>","header") 
%{
#include <QtCore/qstring.h>
#include <QtCore/qbytearray.h>
%}

%fragment("Qt_init", "header",fragment="<qt_string.h>") {
SWIGINTERN int
Qt_init(const QChar *val)
{
    QString qTemp(val);
    std::wstring str = qTemp.toStdWString();
    return qTemp.length();
}
}

%fragment("SWIG_AsQtChPtrAndSize","header",fragment="SWIG_AsCharPtrAndSize",fragment="Qt_init") {
SWIGINTERN int
SWIG_AsQtChPtrAndSize(SV *obj, QChar **val, size_t* psize, int *alloc)
{
  if (!val) {
    return SWIG_AsCharPtrAndSize(obj, 0,  0, 0);    
  } else {
    size_t size;
    char *cptr = 0;
    int calloc = SWIG_OLDOBJ;
    int res = SWIG_AsCharPtrAndSize(obj, &cptr, &size, &calloc);
    if (SWIG_IsOK(res)) {
      STRLEN length = size - 1;
      if (SvUTF8(obj)) {
    int charsEaten = 0;
    unsigned char* sizes = %new_array(size, unsigned char);
    *val = %new_array(size, QChar);
    QString qVal = QString::fromUtf8(cptr);

    for (int i = 0; i < qVal.length(); i++)
    {
        (*val)[i] = qVal.at(i);
    }
    // indicate the end of the string
    (*val)[qVal.length()] = '\0';
    } else {

    QString qVal = QString::fromLocal8Bit(cptr);
    int val_size = qVal.length();
    if (val_size)
    {
        *val = new QChar[val_size+1];
        if (*val)
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < val_size; ++i) {
                (*val)[i] = qVal.at(i);
            }
            (*val)[val_size] = 0;
        }       
    }
    else
        *val = NULL;

      }
      if (psize) *psize = size;
      if (alloc) *alloc = SWIG_NEWOBJ;      
      if (calloc == SWIG_NEWOBJ) %delete_array(cptr);
      return SWIG_NEWOBJ;      
    } else {
      return res;
    }
  }
}
}

%fragment("SWIG_FromQtChPtrAndSize","header",fragment="Qt_init") {
SWIGINTERNINLINE SV *
SWIG_FromQtChPtrAndSize(const QChar* input, size_t size)
{
if (size <= 0)
return NULL;
  SV *output = sv_newmortal();
  int charsEaten = 0;
  int length  = size;                                        // string length
  unsigned char* res = %new_array(length * 13, unsigned char);          // output string

    QString qVal(input, size);
    QByteArray qBytes = qVal.toUtf8();

    char *data = qBytes.data();
    char* pRes = (char*)&res[0];

    while (*data) {
        *pRes = *data;
        ++data;
        pRes++;

    }

  res[qBytes.size()] = '\0';
  sv_setpv((SV*)output, (char *)res );
  SvUTF8_on((SV*)output);
  %delete_array(res);
  return output;
}
}

%include <typemaps/strings.swg>
%typemaps_string(%checkcode(UNISTRING), %checkcode(UNICHAR),
         QChar, QChar,
         SWIG_AsQtChPtrAndSize, 
         SWIG_FromQtChPtrAndSize,
         Qt_init,
         "<qt_string.h>", (-2147483647 - 1), 2147483647);
```

Comment: I can vaguely tell you what the problem is (there's a new parameter for the macro) and what the fix is (implement both `SWIG_CharPtrLen` and `SWIG_CharBufLen` for your QString type), but I'm not actually certain enough what the implementation needs to look like to write a complete answer.

Comment: I found this commit, which describes the problem: https://github.com/swig/swig/commit/88a0e228a9c80bedc414164f17b26be0147da333#diff-c492a429be24092f12884bd5e6b69b70